# check equality of natural number list pair

Tags: coq

I have two natural number list pairs and want to check their equality.

```
Fixpoint beq_natlist (l1 l2 : list*list) : bool :=
 match l1, l2 with
| (nil , nil) => true
| (h :: nil, nil)  => false
| ( nil , h :: nil) => false
| h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2 => if beq_nat h1 h2 then beq_natlist t1 t2 else false

end.
```

Comment: This looks right, except for the parentheses around the patterns in the `match`. What is your issue?

Comment: Also, your type should probably be something like `list nat` instead of `list*list`.

Comment: I think OP wants to define equality of "two natural number list *pairs*" literally, that is, `(list nat * list nat) -> (list nat * list nat) -> bool`.

Comment: error :Expecting 2 patterns but found 1.
Yes, I want to find the equality of  two natural number list pairs.I have updated the code with (list nat * list nat) ,still get the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

First, equality of `list nat`s would look like the following. Note that the multi-match pattern `a, b` and the pair notation `(a, b)` are two totally different things; the former matches two terms, while the latter matches one term which is a pair.

```
Fixpoint beq_natlist (l1 l2 : list nat) : bool :=
  match l1, l2 with
  | nil, nil => true
  | h :: nil, nil => false
  | nil, h :: nil => false
  | h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2 => if beq_nat h1 h2 then beq_natlist t1 t2 else false
  end.
```

Then you can use `beq_natlist` to build the equality of `list nat * list nat`:

```
Fixpoint beq_natlist_pair (p1 p2 : list nat * list nat) : bool :=
  match p1, p2 with
  | (l1, l2), (l3, l4) => beq_natlist l1 l3 && beq_natlist l2 l4
  end.
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem.

Comment: @sanasobia Could you accept the answer then? (If you haven't noticed already, you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark below the up/down arrows.)